# Design choice using node.js and express and socket.io

Tags: node.js, web, socket.io, server

I want to make a web app where every user can create a chat room that other users can join. I would like to have a main node server managing the rooms, and every time a user creates a new room, a new chat server should be started by the main server and it should manage the room.

My question is, how can I make the new server start in node.js and how can I manage it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Socket.io allows you too use the room feature and have the behavior you want (separate chat rooms) without running a separate chat server. Running a separate chat server is not really convenient in node.js because it means running another process, and it makes communication between the main server and the chat servers extra complicated.

What i would advise is using that feature and adopt the following kind of design:

```
io.on('connection', function(socket) {    
    //initialize the object representing the client
    //Your client has not joined a room yet
    socket.on('create_room', function(msg) {
        //initalize the object representing the room
        //Make the client effectively join that room, using socket.join(room_id)
    }
    socket.on('join_room', function(msg) {
        //If the client is currently in a room, leave it using socket.leave(room_id); I am assuming for the sake of simplicity that a user can only be in a single room at all time
        //Then join the new room using socket.join(room_id)
    }
    socket.on('chat_msg', function(msg) {
        //Check if the user is in a room
        //If so, send his msg to the room only using socket.broadcast.to(room_id); That way, every socket that have joined the room using socket.join(room_id) will get the message
    }
}
```

With this design, you're simply adding listeners to event, and once set up, the whole server is running fine without having to deal with concurrency or sub processes.

It's still very minimalist and you'll probably want to handle a few more concepts, such as unique nicknames, or password authentication etc.
But that can easily be done using this design.

Have fun experimenting with socket.io and node.js!

Comment: I am already using this design, but thanks. What I would like is for each user to be able to connect to as many rooms as they like, each room in a new window.

Comment: You can do this aswell using socket.io's room feature! But what you cannot do is knowing from which room came the message without actually specifiying it in say a datastructure along the message.
What have you run into that prevent you from implementing multiple room connections ?

Comment: My concern is that a malicious client might manipulate the room the message came from. So I thought it would be best if the client didn't have to send the room along with the message.

Comment: Exactly, what I would advise is that the server ensures everytime that the user can send the message to the room.

The client would simply do something like `socket.emit('msg', {room:room_id, msg:'Hello World'}` to the server.

And then the server will or will not broadcast the message to the room depending on the rooms that the user joined.
From my point of view this seems to be a acceptable solution. Even if a client have guessed a room_id that he cannot join, he will not be able to join it.

Comment: Well, I will definitely use your solution. Thanks.

Comment: Feel free to comment or post an anwser if you find something else, as I'm also interested in this question ;)